# Laravel Controller Query is giving null output

Tags: laravel

I have written below code

```
$setting = Setting::where('id', 1)->first();
return view('posts.setting', compact('setting'));
```

When I use this variable in my index,

```
<?php $setting = isset($_POST['setting']) ? $_POST['setting'] : 'NULL'; ?>

<?php print_r($setting); ?>
```

I am getting NULL. Why is my query not generating any output?

Comment: Why do you reassigning `$setting` in your blade file?

Comment: removing that did not help either :)

Comment: Can you confirm if you have a row in your setting table with ID as `1` ?

Comment: yes I have a record with Id = 1

Comment: ok, to debug further, can you show your model file? Can you do a `dd($setting)` before `view(.....)` and check what you get.

Comment: @vivek_23 - I did dd($setting) in view - i still get the same error. Just to try out, I did following: `Route::get('test', function() {

    $setting = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM settings '));

    dd($setting);


});` and I got the response from DB

Comment: Do a dd() before you write `return view(..)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of all users, It had seeded database tables. I ran the following command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

and it started working. Not sure why it could not fetch manually created record but took it once I ran db seed

Answer (score 1):

why are you using $_POST you don't need

```php
@php 
    $setting = isset($setting) ? $setting : 'NULL'; 
    print_r($setting);
@endphp
```

Comment: Still, received NULL as a response.

Comment: try to print_r($setting); die; in controller. maybe $setting is null. means data for id 1 not exist

Answer (score 0):

If a record exists with id 1 then return a view with data otherwise dump and die in the controller **just for your testing**.

In controller:

```
     $setting = Setting::find(1);

     if($setting){
         return view('posts.setting', compact('setting'));
     } else {
         dd('No record found!');
     }
```